# Can only access homepage and admin panel

Tags: migration, apache, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am really struggling to move Wordpress from an external host to my localhost (xampp).  After two days trying to do this I am now at the stage where I can access the homepage and admin panel, but nothing else.

I have accessed permalinks and clicked save as shown below:

[image]

Here is the .htaccess file that is generated:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here is the apache config:

Options All

  AllowOverride All

and:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

For example, when I try to access: http://ianscomputer/Blog/about-2/; I see this in Fiddler:

[image]

What is the problem?

**Update**
Here are some more settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you updated `wp-config.php`, `wp-options` table in database and changed both site url and website url in admin panel?

Comment: @Jack Johansson, I have added three more screenshots to my question in answer to your questions.

Comment: @Jack Johansson, I have also noticed that I cannot browse to: http://ianscomputer/blog - I can only browse to: http://localhost/blog.  If I change the wp-options values to http://localhost/blog then I cannot browse to http://localhost/blog, but I can browse to http://ianscomputer/blog.

Comment: you forgot the ending `/` in your URLs. Try adding that and see if it helps after clearing the cache.

Comment: @ Jack Johansson, I will try that and report back.  Hold on...

Comment: By the way, what's wrong with just using `localhost` as url?

Comment: @Jack Johansson, adding a forward slash has made no difference.

Comment: @Jack Johansson, do you know how I can debug this? I cannot picture what is going on.  For what I read it is as if: site 1 is redirecting to site 2 and site 2 is redirecting back to site 1.  However, WP_HOME and WP_SiteURL have the same values.

Comment: In some hosting providers, you need the blog URL and site URL to be `localhost` for it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy to debug a server configuration entirely by remote. Debugging is not as easy as solving programming issues. I could help you if i had access to your computer.

Comment: @kabir, I am trying to set this up on my local pc.

Comment: @Jack Johansson, I wander if a new front end would help? I.e. Import the existing database to local host and refresh the php files?

Comment: Yes, but you will need the plugins too. Before that, you can try switching to a new theme, maybe it's a theme issue.

Comment: @w0051977 were you able to solve this issue? If not, based on your screenshot, your pages are getting redirected by either Apache, wp-config, theme, or plug-in. Check this first for Apache: [How to trace Apache 301 Moved Permanently?](http://serverfault.com/questions/361165/how-to-trace-apache-301-moved-permanently)

Answer (score 0):

@w0051977 after re-reading this issue, I started thinking of something that could be the actual issue; your "domain name".

**Please note:** I always work on Windows, so I could be wrong in some or all areas. I'm trying to use my best guess work here.

During my test environments (local), I always have a top-level domain name, e.g. **ianscomputer.internal**. While I was learning WP, I had some difficulties because I was using only localhost.  Honestly, I didn't take the time to learn why, so I just created a fake "full domain name" and moved on.

Based on the stated above, I did a quick Google search and came across this post: [Faking a top-level domain name for local development with Apache](https://blog.gaya.ninja/articles/faking-a-top-level-domain-name-for-local-development-with-apache/) which says:

> Not every CMS (looking at you Wordpress!) has relative paths to their content.

So I would say:

1. Follow the steps to create a fake top-level domain. (Super guess x3)
2. Check Apache settings as suggested on this post: [How to trace Apache 301 Moved Permanently?]https://serverfault.com/questions/361165/how-to-trace-apache-301-moved-permanently.
3. Get rid of the **:80** in all settings. When using http:// before the domain, this is stated. (Personal opinion)
4. While testing, change your permalink structure to **Default**. It will make your troubleshooting easier. (Personal opinion)

Test the above and let us know what works and does not work.

I hope this helps and good luck.